# Is there a way to solve the optimizer error?

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch

I have an error in my code, is there a way to solve.
I have initialized my weights

```
weight_1 = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(128,128)).cuda()
weight_2 = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(128,128)).cuda()
optimizer= optim.Adam([{‘params’:model.parameters()}, {‘params’: [weight_1, weight_2]}], lr=1e-5)
```

Error

```
Value Error: cannot optimize a non-leaf tensor.
```

Comment: Where do you use `weight_1` and `weight_2`? If they are not used in a model, there is no meaning in optimizing them.

Comment: I have used them in my model within model forward function.